# Jquery removeClass() on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi i have this problem: I want to click on div which will flipped (this is work) but next step is flipp div back on click on "x" (this is my problem).

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="balik">
        <div class="panel panel-default panel-cube">
            <div class=" flip">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="panel-body face front">
                        <h4>Balík 28 dní</h4>
                        <br>
                        <h1>16,80€</h1>
                        <br>
                        <h4>Zisti viac o balíku &raquo;</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body face back">
                        <p class="close">x</p>  <a href="#"><h4>O Balíku 28 dní</h4></a>
                        &raquo; celkom 28 dní na topovanie
                        <br />&raquo; 5 topovaných inzerátov
                        <br />&raquo; -30% z ceny oproti balíku 7 dní
                        <br />
                        <br>
                        <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Kúpiť</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY code:

```
$(function(){
$('.flip').click(function(){
    $(this).find('.card').addClass('flipped')
    });// this is work

$('.close').click(function(){
        $('.flip').find('.card.flipped').removeClass('flipped')
    }); // this is not work
});
```

Thanks for answers.

Comment: can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AhXLH/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `.flipped` is essentially a dynamically-created element, you'd need to use event delegation:

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/7Zg92/

```
$(document).on('click', '.close', function () {
    $('.flip').find('.card.flipped').removeClass('flipped')
});
```

Comment: check my fiddle @isherwood why this is not working i logged click is fired:http://jsfiddle.net/3j76g/

Comment: thanks for answer. This is working :) I was clicking on same div and p tag at once? For it did not work?

Comment: There is no dynamically created element here.

Comment: This will solve the problem, but the explained reason is plain _wrong_.

Comment: The operative word was "essentially", as it it must be treated like one. Rather that empty criticism, why not offer a better explanation?

Comment: The element is only hidden, changing style's display property differs from dynamically creating an element, my point was this. Your code solves the problem, just because the handler is called after the `.flip`'s click handler, the `close` handler basically is called after  that (_because of the event delegation with the document object as the target_). Sorry event delegation here is not the answer, it's a remedy.

Comment: Thank you for that. Alas, I can't downvote or delete.

Answer (score 2):

That's because events bubble up, you should stop the propagation of the event:

```
$('.close').click(function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    $('.flip').find('.card.flipped').removeClass('flipped');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aaLUs/

Comment: This would seem to be a better solution. I'm curious now why my answer even works.